# async await calling long running sync AND async methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp.net web api 2 and Entity Framework 6.

**Original pseudo code**

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProductLabel(int productId)
{
      var productDetails = repository.GetProductDetails(productId); 
      var label = labelCalculator.Render(productDetails);  
      return Ok(label);
}
```

**Modified code**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProductLabel(int productId)
{
      var productDetails = await repository.GetProductDetailsAsync(productId); // 1 long second as this call goes into sub services
      var label = labelCalculator.Render(productDetails); // 1.5 seconds synchrounous code
      return Ok(label);
}
```

Before my change everything ran synchronously.

After my change the call to a remote service which is calling again a database is done the async-await way.

Then I do a sync call to a rendering library which offers only sync methods. The calculation takes 1,5 seconds.

Is there still a benefit that I did the remote database_service call the async-await way but the 2nd call not? And is there anything I could still improve?

**Note**

The reason why I ask this is because:

*"With async controllers when a process is waiting for I/O to complete, its thread is freed up for the server to use for processing other requests."*

So when the first remote database_service call is processing and awaiting for that 1 second the thread is returned to IIS??!!

But what about the 2nd label calculation taking 1,5 seconds that will block the current thread again for 1,5 seconds ?

So I release and block the thread, that does not make sense or what do you think?

Comment: You don't use `Task.FromResult` when you have `async`, just do `return label;` did you mean to not use async/await in your first example?

Comment: I know... therefore I presented you the "modified code", which is what you suggest now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering library is not simply "blocking a thread", it is doing work performing your rendering. There is nothing better you can do.

Comment: Please also address my first question:"Is there still a benefit that I did the remote database_service call the async-await way but the 2nd call not?" Thanks :-)

Comment: You call the remote method the async await way in both examples. I brought that up to you in a comment. Your first code won't even compile so I cant say how it would compare, because the first code can't run.

Comment: Therefore I wrote "pseude code" so It can not compile. YES I did not mean await in my first sample. That was a copy/paste typo. I corrected it now.

Comment: In that case there is a benefit to doing async-await for only the first call, during that 1 second you are waiting for the database to respond the server could process another incoming request. This will increase the maximum number of concurrent requests your server can support.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous code creates a certain continuation under the hood, it is a sort of synthetic sugar to make asynchronous programming feel more synchonious.

In general, depending on the operations themselves, it could help to make both long running tasks asynchronous. It would use different tasks under the hood for each different long running task and run them asynchronously.

At the moment, these tasks run completely synchoniously within GetProductLabel, meaning that if it is the only method you are calling you would not tell th difference between synchonious code.

If it is possible I would make the second method async, since I am not familiar with any sagnificant drawbacks of using tasks and async await.

In your case there is nothing better you can do, and it won't make much difference, since you have to run it synchronously, as you are using the result from the first method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there still a benefit that I did the remote database_service call
>   the async-await way but the 2nd call not?

Yes, this call is now non-blocking and can run alongside other code, even though it is only for 1 second.

> And is there anything I could still improve?

If you can have the second call run asynchronously too, the whole method can run asynchronously and won't block at all.

Comment: Will the now non-blocking call return the thread to the caller for that 1 second, so that IIS can put another http request on this thread? Or is the thread only returned to the caller when the method call is async-await all the way up?

Comment: It will return the thread for that 1 second. Think of it this way: *all* non-async statements block the current thread---even something like `var s = "Hello, World."`---it just happens so fast it doesn't matter. Many async methods have statements like this, but that doesn't stop them from leveraging the benefits of async. Your second blocking call behaves the same---it doesn't stop other async calls working asynchronously, it just takes a long time.